# From $\int_0^1\int_z^1z\phi''\circ\phi^{-1}(z)[\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}(z)]^{-1}[\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}(t)]^{-1}dt\;dz$ to $\int_0^\infty s\phi(s)\phi''(s)ds$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Can someone explain how the author evaluates these integrals?

$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\int_z^1z\phi''\circ\phi^{-1}(z)[\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}(z)]^{-1}[\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}(t)]^{-1}\;dt\;dz \tag1\\[4pt]
=&\int_0^1z\phi''\circ\phi^{-1}(z)[\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}(z)]^{-1}[-\phi^{-1}(z)]\;dz \tag2\\[4pt]
=&\int_0^\infty s\;\phi(s)\cdot\phi''(s)\;ds \tag3
\end{align}$$

where $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $\phi$. But I am not sure if $[\dots]^{-1}$ means the inverse function or if it means $1/[\dots]$.

Can someone explain to me how they evaluate the $dt$ integral in the first step?

Furthermore, can someone explain what the author does in the last step? I dont understand this substitution or whatever is happening there.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from the first line to the second, we can make the substitution $u=\phi^{-1}(t)$. Differentiating $\phi(u)=t$ gives $\phi'(u)du=dt$, so
$$\int_z^1\dfrac{1}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(t))}\,dt=\int_{\phi^{-1}(z)}^{\phi^{-1}(1)}\frac{1}{\phi'(u)}\phi'(u)\,du=\int_{\phi^{-1}(z)}^{\phi^{-1}(1)}du=\phi^{-1}(1)-\phi^{-1}(z)$$
You haven't told us what $\phi$ is, but we must have $\phi^{-1}(1)=0$ to get the result in the second line.

To go from the second line to the third line, make the substitution $s=\phi^{-1}(z)$:

$$\begin{aligned}\int z\phi''(\phi^{-1}(z))[\phi'(\phi^{-1}(z)]^{-1}[-\phi^{-1}(z)]\,dz&=\int \phi(s)\,\phi''(s)\,[\phi'(s)]^{-1}\cdot s\cdot\phi'(s)\,ds\\&=\int s\,\phi(s)\,\phi''(s)\,ds \end{aligned}$$